# Named/user locks on informix

Tags: locking, informix

Do they exist? I'm used to do explicit locking on Oracle using dbms_lock, but can't find anything similar on Informix.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle uses MVCC to control access to the data in the database, for the most part.

Informix and DB2 (amongst other DBMS) use locking most of the time.

There are statements to lock tables:

```
LOCK TABLE tablename IN { SHARE | EXCLUSIVE } MODE;
```

If your database is not logged, you can unlock a table with:

```
UNLOCK TABLE tablename;
```

If your database is logged (the normal state of affairs), then you can only lock a table inside a transaction and the lock is released when the transaction is committed or rolled back.

Additionally, cursors with the FOR UPDATE clause apply locks to rows.  You then need to know about isolation levels because the duration of the read lock depends on isolation level, though update locks (because a row is changed) always last to end of transaction.

Indeed, if you're running with REPEATABLE READ (aka SERIALIZABLE — there's a complex story behind Informix's isolation levels vs the standard isolation levels), then all statements apply locks to rows processed, and even to predicates used to determine which rows were processed.  This is necessary to ensure the isolation.

Comment: I understand what you say, but I'm not interested on blocking rows or tables but processes. Let's suppouse(naive example) that I have a long lived Stored Procedure that inserts a PK(externally generated) if not exists and updates a count if it does. If two calls to that SP happens at the same time, one of them will fail because both will try to insert a PK. In PL/SQL, I can use a semaphore to ensure mutual exclusion(via dbms_lock.acquire). I would like to do the same in Informix, if it's possible.

Comment: With the right constraints in place (duplicate values not allowed), only one of the two procedures will be able to insert a given PK value.  The DBMS takes charge of that, automatically.  The SPL (stored procedure language) has an exception mechanism that can be used to recover from the failure to insert.  I'm not sure that there's a huge benefit to adding locks as you describe; they are not built into the system, but could be simulated fairly easily if you really wanted to do so, but I'm still not sure that there's a benefit (other than not changing code) to doing so.

Comment: One article on Oracle DBMS_LOCK indicates that one reason why you need them in Oracle is that one session cannot see another session's updates.  That isn't an issue in Informix or other lock-based DBMS.  Subject to isolation level, a session can see another session's changes once committed by the other session.  I'd need to see a detailed example of what you're doing and why the locks are necessary in Oracle to have a chance of working out whether there's a problem to be resolved in Informix, but from the limited and rapid scanning I've done, I'm not sure there's a need for them in Informix.

Comment: It was a made up example to illustrate the use, not to justify the necessity. A better example could be to avoid having overlapping time ranges, something that cannot be easily solved via constraints. Anyway, I understand from your response that the answer it's just "no, they don't exist". Thanks.